# how to minimize the usage of conversion functions in SQL queries?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

My SQL Queries contain lots of ltrim() , rtrim() , substring() etc conversion functions...They are significantly impacting query performance... Please answer my following queries :

- How to minimize usage of conversion functions in my queries?
- What are the possible alternatives instead of conversion functions that could be used in queries ?
- will the alternatives significantly improve my query performance ?

...please guide me

Comment: Do you know why these functions are impacting performance?  Is it the time spent executing the functions, or their negative impact on execution plans?  Usually, the CPU time spent manipulating strings is irrelevant compared to the IO time spent reading and writing data.

Comment: You can handle these conversion functions like ltrim,Rtrim,Substring can be handled in the front-end while getting inputs.

Comment: @ jon earles:- these functions are consuming time in execution

Answer (score 1):

How do you know these functions are consuning time in execution? have you run it without these functions and noticed that it is quicker?

Are all the columns in the where clause indexed?

If you look at the query plan can you see table scans?

How many rows are in this table?

You could create a new column in your table that contains cleaned up data out of the emp_info column. i.e.

```
UPDATE YourTable SET NewColumn = ltrim(rtrim(substr(emp_info, 1, 9)))
```

Then add a trigger to your table to ensure it is always up to date

Then add an index to the column.

Then alter your select to use the new column

You might see some performance improvement. It's impossible to say based on the information you've given.

Comment: Yes i tried executing my SQL query without using conversion functions and there is a significant difference in execution time. The columns in where clause are not indexed. There are more than 2 million rows in this table. What you suggested would require changes in database structure ..right ?? Is my understanding correct??

Answer (score 0):

You can handle these conversion functions like ltrim,Rtrim,Substring can be handled in the front-end while getting inputs. These types of string function is availiable in the front end too. For eg: Trim(),Substring()

Comment: Modifying front end or database are out of scope as it is handled by external entities...My Application fetches data from DB, processes it and gives output. So please suggest what could be used instead of conversion functions.

Comment: select to_char(emp_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as LABEL, ltrim(rtrim(substr(emp_record, 9, 16))) as VALUE ;
from schemaName.table1 a, schemaName.table2 b where ltrim(rtrim(substr(emp_info, 1, 9))) = 'T M 0' and a.emp_no = b.emp_no and emp_source = 2 and emp_date > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6);
order by emp_date;

Comment: Also putting this in the front end means all data gets sucked over to the client for processing. This may not be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a little amount of time by replacing `ltrim(rtrim(` with `trim(`

Example:

```
create table test1(a varchar2(4000));

--Create 1 million rows
--This is hopefully a "large" amount of rows, but small enough to fit
--in memory.  This way we can test the CPU time to process the rows
--instead of the IO time to read the data.
begin
    for i in 1 .. 10 loop
        insert into test1 select '          '||level||'          '
        from dual connect by level <= 100000;
    end loop;
    commit;
end;
/

--Note: You'll want to run the statements several times first to
--"warm up" the database, and get everything in memory.

--0.33 seconds
select count(*)
from test1
where ltrim(rtrim(a)) = '5';

--0.20 seconds
select count(*)
from test1
where trim(a) = '5';
```

But this is a very small amount of time to save on processing 1 million rows.

How long does it take your system to process the 2 million rows?  Is there something unusual about your data?  For example, are you using large CLOBs instead of small VARCHAR2s?  Are you sure that the problem isn't caused by the predicates creating a different explain plan?  For example, Oracle might think that the functions return significantly fewer rows than they really do, and is therefore using a nested loop
instead of a hash join.